# CSS: Tell block element to fill in height

Tags: html, css

This seems like it should be the easiest thing in the world, but I'm having difficulties. I'm started to think I didn't know as much about CSS as I thought, or CSS was designed more poorly than I thought.

I have a page. At the top, there's an arbitrary amount of markup. Then there's a block element. All I want to do is make this block element extend its height to the bottom of the window.

See http://jsfiddle.net/vHVeC/4/. It's close, but the last block element extends beyond the visible area of the browser, creating scrollbars. No content should extend beyond the dimensions of the viewport (ie there should be no scrollbars).

How can I do this with having to use JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with CSS - getting an element to fill 100% of the remaining vertical space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793976/help-with-css-getting-an-element-to-fill-100-of-the-remaining-vertical-space)

Comment: This is not the same. While the titles are similar, the scenario isn't when you read through the problem, and the accepted answer does not answer my question. :)

Comment: @Snickers So, you want no scrolling at all. Or, do you want the block element to have a min-width?

Comment: @Šime: The red box should fill to the bottom without creating scrollbars. The window should not scroll.

Comment: @Snickers Do you know the height of the content above? Is it a fixed height?

Comment: @Šime: Unfortunately, no. The height may be different each time the page is rendered. I'm really not sure this is possible without using JavaScript.

Comment: @Snickers Then use a table. Do you know how to do it, or do you need a solution?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is how you can do it using a table (It's pure CSS):

http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/table-layout.html

Comment: The link is dead but the copy is in archive.org https://web.archive.org/web/20110810063955/http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/table-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [CSS has massive troubles finding heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931187/css-metaphysics-why-is-page-vertical-alignment-so-difficult).  Widths, no worries.

Using Javascript, you'd go:

```
//Grab div element
var obj = document.getElementById('theDiv');

//Enable sizing
obj.style.position = 'relative';

//Force to window
obj.style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight+'px';
```

Incidentally, in your Fiddle, the plaintext node above the `div` is offsetting the `div` below.  It's finding 100% of the body height, but then being bumped down, causing the scrollbar.  The way to fix this in CSS is `position:absolute;left:0;top:0` which locks it in place.

Also note that in any of these cases, if you do end up scrolling (e.g. to 150%), you'll see the bottom edge of your `div` down there at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You've hit the [css box model problem](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=E0989953B6F20B41). A quick and dirty solution is to set the [`overflow: hidden`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) property to prevent the scrollbars but you should be very careful doing this. You will need to make sure your content fits on screen as any content extending beyond the block element will be inaccessible to users.